# Lookup table/palette shader on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es, shader, glsl

I have a fragment shader with the following:

```
const lowp float colors[8] = float[8]( // line 12
    0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,1
);
```

but it fails to compile:

```
ERROR: 0:12: 'array of float' : array type not supported here in glsl < 120 
ERROR: 0:12: 'array of float' : constructor not supported for type 
ERROR: 0:15: 'array of float' : no matching overloaded function found 
ERROR: 0:12: 'const lowp float' : cannot declare arrays of this type 
ERROR: 0:12: 'colors' : redefinition
```

How can I define a lookup table in GLSL? The input texture has values from an enum, each value of which I want to be mapped to a different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 1D texture as a lookup table.

Comment: GLES2.0 doesn't support 1D textures, but I used a 2D texture of height 1.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf), section 4.1.9:

"There is no mechanism for initializing arrays at declaration time from within a shader."